# What will be the force when you push a wall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

force is change in velocity times mass so if i push a wall there will be no change in velocity of the wall it will be in rest,acceralation will be 0, and so the force should be zero.So it means that force applied on a wall will always be zero ? Is this logic correct or not ?

Comment: Please see the definition of force.

Comment: It's not just you vs. the wall. The wall is attached to the Earth—it effectively is an extension _of_ the Earth. When you push against the wall with your hands, you effectively are pushing against the Earth. But at the same time, you also are pushing against the Earth in another direction with your feet. And then, there also is a small matter gravity. If neither you nor the Earth is accelerated, then you may infer that the vector sum of all of those forces acting between yourself and the Earth is zero.

Answer (score 1):

> force is change in velocity times mass

It is the net force on an object that causes a change in velocity (acceleration). An object can be subjected to a forces without undergoing an acceleration if the net force is zero.

> So if i push a wall there will be no change in velocity of the wall it
>   will be in rest,acceralation will be 0, and so the force should be
>   zero.So it means that force applied on a wall will always be zero ? Is
>   this logic correct or not ?

No it is not correct. The acceleration of the wall is zero *because the net force on the wall is zero.*

When you push on a wall with a force F, the wall pushes back on you with and equal and opposite force F per Newton's third law. If the wall is firmly fixed to some structure, the wall does not accelerate because the structure exerts a force F equal and opposite to the force you exerted on the wall. The net force on the wall is zero and the wall does not accelerate.

Meanwhile, since the wall exerts a force of F on you why don't you accelerate? Probably because the static friction between your feet and the floor exerts a force equal to F opposite to the force the wall exerts on you. The net force on you is zero, and you do not accelerate.

Neither you nor the wall accelerates, but you know there is a force between you and the wall, because you can feel it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> In physics, a force is any interaction that, when unopposed, will change the motion of an object. A force can cause an object with mass to change its velocity (which includes to begin moving from a state of rest), i.e., to accelerate.

[Force definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force)

Note the word "unopposed".

Imagine you have been kidnapped by gangsters who want to intimidate you. They put your head into a great big vise and start cranking it shut. Your head does not get any significant acceleration so physicists might possibly say there is no net force. But....

> In an extended body, each part usually applies forces on the adjacent parts; the distribution of such forces through the body is the internal mechanical stress. Such internal mechanical stresses cause no acceleration of that body as the forces balance one another. [....] Stress usually causes deformation of solid materials, or flow in fluids.

Answer (score 0):

The force will balance because the force applied by us is not enough to overcome the friction  force of wall and hence wall doesn't move and force is balanced
Hope this helpful!!

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is flawed because when you apply a force on a wall, there is a contact force which opposes this (Newton's third law). Hence net force on the wall will be zero. As mass of the wall is not zero, acceleration has to be zero.

Comment: Newtown's third Law has nothing to do,  Reaction force is aplied on you. The force that balances the push comes from the structure of the wall.

Answer (score -1):

So if f=ma, the force applied is equal to the mass of the person applying the force and 0 acceleration which means the force is 0. You are actually applying no force according to physics. But you know you are applying the force because you can feel your muscles taking the pain of pushing the massive wall.